# ERROR: syntax error at or near "$$

Tags: postgresql

I am a newbie on Postgres.

I try to convert an Oracle PL/SQL script to Postgres.
At this, it's not a succes !

Here is a simple code with errors :

```
    $$
DECLARE

  Err_Exec         numeric;                -- Erreur d'execution.


BEGIN


  Err_Exec     := 0;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which reports:

```
:13: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$$
```

Any idea to this error when executing ?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a complete statement.

You need a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement if you're trying to create a function, or a `DO` block if you're trying to run a one-off procedure.

For one-off `DO` blocks, it should look like

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
BEGIN
 .... plpgsql code here ...
END;
$$;
```